# How can I make multiple scans using the BLUENRG-M0

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluenrg

I am developing a simple scanner using the BLUENRG-M0 from ST. I have a custom board wtih an MSP430F5255

I just want to make multiple scans to discover other devices of interest around.

I am following the ACI API from ST and my first scan is successful. However, I cannot make a second scan. When I call twice the aci_discover function, an error occurred.

So if someone has done it before on a projet or has an idea to how achieve this, I would be thankfully.

Best regards,

Guillaume Bara